# AWS-CDK API-GW Custom Domain Base Path Mapping setting Stage

Tags: stage, api-gateway, aws-cdk, custom-domain

How to set 'Stage' using AWS-CDK in API-GW Custom Domain Base Path Mapping?

[image]

Here is the aws-cdk code that creates api-gw custom domain with base path mapping, but the stage is set as '*'
I need to set it to a specific stage
How can I do that?

cdk version: 1.6.1 (build a09203a)

```
      const restApiObj = {
        node: this.node,
        stack: Stack.of(this),
        restApiId: api.ref
      };
      this.customDomainName = new apiGateway.DomainName(this, "DomainName", {
        endpointType: EndpointType.REGIONAL,
        certificate: {
          certificateArn: props.customDomainNameProps.customDomainNameCertificateARN,
          node: this.node,
          stack: Stack.of(this)
        },
        domainName: (props.customDomainNameProps.customDomainName)?props.customDomainNameProps.customDomainName:defaultApiGWDomainName,
      });

      this.customDomainName.addBasePathMapping(restApiObj, {
        basePath: (props.customDomainNameProps.domainNameBasePathMapping?props.customDomainNameProps.domainNameBasePathMapping : ApigwConstruct.API_GW_DEFAULT_BASE_MAPPING)
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way of how solving this, by using low level constructs - CfnBaseMapping, here is the code:

```
const basePathMapping = new CfnBasePathMapping(this, "basePathMapping", {
        basePath: (props.customDomainNameProps.domainNameBasePathMapping?props.customDomainNameProps.domainNameBasePathMapping : ApigwConstruct.API_GW_DEFAULT_BASE_MAPPING),
        domainName: this.customDomainName.domainName,
        restApiId: api.ref,
        stage: props.stageName
      });
```